# FieldConverter ConverterKind.Date not supporting "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff"

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format, flat-file, filehelpers

I'm trying to read a delimited flat file using file helper library.

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff")]
public DateTime DateOfInteraction;
```

But I'm getting the following exception

> FileHelpers.ConvertException was unhandled
>     HResult=-2146233088
>     Message=Error Converting '2015-09-20 23:40:07.707000' to type: 'DateTime'.  Using the format: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff'
>     Source=FileHelpers
>     ColumnNumber=80
>     FieldName=DateOfInteraction
>     FieldStringValue=2015-09-20 23:40:07.707000
>     LineNumber=2
>     MessageExtra= Using the format: 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff'
>     MessageOriginal=Error Converting '2015-09-20 23:40:07.707000' to type: 'DateTime'. 
>     StackTrace:
>          at FileHelpers.ConvertHelpers.DateTimeConverter.StringToField(String from)
>          at FileHelpers.FieldBase.AssignFromString(ExtractedInfo fieldString, LineInfo line)
>          at FileHelpers.FieldBase.ExtractFieldValue(LineInfo line)
>          at FileHelpers.RecordOperations.StringToRecord(Object record, LineInfo line, Object[] values)
>          at FileHelpers.FileHelperAsyncEngine`1.ReadNextRecord()
>          at FileHelpers.FileHelperAsyncEngine`1.ReadNext()
>          at FileHelpers.FileHelperAsyncEngine`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext()
>          at TestApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\MSRS\Old Sys\Practice\CIMStats\TestApplication\Program.cs:line 22
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:

I didn't understand why I'm getting the exception even though the date format string is a valid one. The following code snippet giving proper output...

```
Console.WriteLine("Started: {0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff}", DateTime.Now);
```

[image: DateTime format]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195820/fieldconverter-converterkind-date-dd-mm-yyyy-exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"/" in a custom date format string is  a culture-specific DateSeparator. So it is being replaced by the date separator for your culture. While converting you have to specify `InvariantCulture` in culture settings while converting

Comment: Great point @AksheyBhat I did not know that. I will add a warning in the converter.
MSRS you can also read that field as String and later convert it in you code when needed